# Is there a special way to finding a nonzero vector v that belongs to both the null space and the column space of a square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

In my textbook is it written that for some special cases the column space and the nullspace of a square matrix can have nonzero vectors (**v**) in common. I wonder if there is any special type of matrix for which this statement is always true, or how one would go about to finding such vectors **v** in the general case?

Comment: *"I wonder if there is any special type of matrix for which this statement is always true"*, yes, this occurs **iff** $\text{rank}\Big(A^2\Big)\lt \text{rank}\Big(A\Big)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a vector $\mathbf v$ satisfies

1. $\mathbf v = A \mathbf w$ for some $\mathbf w$.
2. $A \mathbf v = \mathbf 0$.

Putting these two facts together tells us that $A^2 \mathbf w = \mathbf 0$, which is the first step to finding such a $\mathbf v$.

We can find all the vectors $\mathbf w$ that will work by finding a basis for the null space of $A^2$. Then, we can multiply each of the vectors in the basis by $A$. If any of the results are nonzero, they give a possible value of $\mathbf v$. If not, then there is no intersection.

This generalizes to finding the intersection between the null space of a matrix and the column space of another matrix.